# How to use body parameters in an http POST (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, http, post

The following piece of code IS working.
It uses the query string to POST.

```
NSString *URLString = @"https://www.mysecret.com/api";
NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    [parameters setValue:@"user" forKey:@"username"];
    [parameters setValue:@"pass" forKey:@"password"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters error:nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    return operation;
```

I've gone through countless tutorials and can not figure out how to simply add these username and password parameters to the body of the POST ... as opposed to passing them through the url string.

Any help would be amazing!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your own post bodies. Unlike query parameters, there are multiple possible post body formats.

What content type does you post need to be?

Once you know the content type, you can format the post body accordingly. If you are using a common format like `application/json`, then you can use a canned solution like `AFJSONRequestSerializer`.